# undefined method `afterlogin_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f79311c5c80>:0x007f79311c5280>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

** i am getting an error as undefined method but i have already defined my instance variable in controller i dont know what to do i am new to ruby
i have created a form in which i will enter details and save it on button click so there is this page new in which my form will be displayed and i have written the code in controller which will flash a message that data is saved when i will click on submit

** this is my controller

```
 class AfterloginController < ApplicationController 


 def adminview

  end

  def new    
    @afterlogin = Afterlogin.new
    if @afterlogin.save
      flash[:notice] = "description created successfully."
    else
      flash[:notice] = "description creation failed."
    end
  end
  def regularview
  end
end
```

this is my view

```
<%= form_for @afterlogin do |f| %>


<p>
  <%= f.label :UserName %>
  <%= f.text_area :UserName %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :Description %>
  <%= f.text_area :Description %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :Date %>
  <%= f.text_feild :Date %>
</p>
<p>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
</p>

<% end %>
```

** this is my db migration file

```
    class CreateAfterlogins < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    create_table :afterlogins do |t|

      t.string  "UserName" 
      t.text "Description"
      t.date "Date"
    end
  end
  def down
        drop_table :afterlogins

  end
end
```

** this is route file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 

get 'afterlogin/adminview'

  get 'afterlogin/new'

  get 'afterlogin/regularview'   


  get 'login/loginDetails'
```

Comment: Are you getting this error on submitting the form? Also show us your `routes`

Comment: when i am running the server and entering the route the page didnt open instead it gives this error

Comment: What does `rake routes` produce ?

Comment: Prefix Verb URI Pattern                       Controller#Action                   
  afterlogin_adminview GET  /afterlogin/adminview(.:format)   afterlogin#adminview                
        afterlogin_new GET  /afterlogin/new(.:format)         afterlogin#new                      
afterlogin_regularview GET  /afterlogin/regularview(.:format) afterlogin#regularview              
    login_loginDetails GET  /login/loginDetails(.:format)     login#loginDetails

Comment: this is my rake routes

Comment: From what `rake routes`produce, available xx_path methods are:
* afterlogin_adminview_path
* afterlogin_new_path
* login_loginDetails_path

Comment: <%= form_for @afterlogin do |f| %> -this line gives the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method `afterlogin_path' for
>   Class:0x007f79311c5c80>:0x007f79311c5280

Your routes are not **proper**. As you are having `@afterlogin`(*which is a resource*),Rails will look for its *Restfulroute*. You should have

`resources :afterlogins`

in  your `routes.rb` which should solve your problem. Also make sure you have `create` action in the controller.

Comment: so i should replace my route file to resources : afterlogins ?

Comment: @HarshitJohri Don't replace! Just place that in the `routes.rb` and check